# UWP/WPF- Is there a better way to manage resources other than a per-page basis?

Tags: wpf, layout, resources, uwp, styling

I'm building a UWP app and am noticing that each page's xaml tends to get very scattered-looking. There's one case where I have a few hundred lines of styling code using a visualstatemanager, and then half as much code on the actual layout of the page.

Is there a way to split out resources into other files so that my layout and my styling are relatively independent of each other, similar to how you have HTML/CSS on the web? Or do I just have to live with these large blocks of styling on each of my pages?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for [merged dictionaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references)? (also [here is something](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178(v=vs.100).aspx) about this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course there is. Just create a resource dictionary and apply some style in it (Don't forget to put x:Key to your style, you will need it to "call" the style form other pages), like the one below:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem" x:Key="CustomGridviewStyle">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,4,4"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource GridViewItemMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter
            ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
            SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True"
            CheckBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
            CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumBrush}"
            DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
            DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
            FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}"
            FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
            PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
            PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}"
            PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
            SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}"
            SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
            SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}"
            PressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}"
            SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}"
            DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
            DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
            ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource GridViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
            VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
            ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
            CheckMode="Overlay"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

After that you can put this dictionary to your app xaml in order to not define it to every page you use. Like that:

```
<Application
    x:Class="App1.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    RequestedTheme="Light">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="test.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

And finally you can call the style like this:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <GridView Name="gvTest"
                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CustomGridviewStyle}">
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, the grammar use URI. It has two styles, beginning with `"pack://"` or `appointing as a relative path`.

For example: `"/ResourceWPF;component/xxxFolder/xxx.xaml"`

- the First one means app's name.
- The second means the dictionary is a component under the app's folder.

while the UWP use the mode: `"ms-appx:///ResourceUWP/xxxFolder/xxx.xaml"`

By the way, the visual studio sometimes will make some errors which are hard to believe. Such as `Page.Resources` can just only be set once. Take the `<ResourceDictionary>` tag to the end of the article.

1. clean solution
2. build solution
3. If this cannot get through, reopen your visual studio.

> It's better to set the ResourceDictionary in app.xaml.cs. That should be worked in the environment. If this cannot work, try to add a ClassLibrary to the solution, add the ResourceDictionary to ClassLibrary. Then you use `"ms-appx:///App_name/file_name.xaml"`. Hope this help.